# SocketException after long wait for response in HessianProxyFactory

Tags: java, httpclient, socketexception, hessian

I have a proxy created by HessianProxyFactory.
After running call to the server and wait 6:40min (in this time server running query on db and wait more than this time for data response) (400 secs) the client throws `SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server`.

```
    final String url = createUrl(baseUrl, consoleInterface);
    final HessianProxyFactory factory = new HessianProxyFactory();
    try {
        factory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);

        return (IRemoteAPIBase) factory.create(
            consoleInterface.getInterfaceClass(),
            url
        );
    }
```

Here is the stack:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1676)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1672)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
    at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianURLConnection.sendRequest(HessianURLConnection.java:125)
    at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.sendRequest(HessianProxy.java:296)
    at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.invoke(HessianProxy.java:171)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getCouponVoucherHistoryReportData(Unknown Source)
    at pl.upos.csak.console.client.remote.ReportingClient$1.makeCall(ReportingClient.java:84)
    at pl.upos.csak.console.client.remote.ReportingClient$1.makeCall(ReportingClient.java:1)
    at pl.upos.common.remoting.base.RemoteAPIClientBase$RemoteCall.execute(RemoteAPIClientBase.java:89)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:778)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:775)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1324)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianURLConnection.sendRequest(HessianURLConnection.java:112)
    ... 8 more
```

How to change this time from 400 secs to longer?
I tried setConnectTimeout but that doesn't work.

Comment: This is not a timeout. It is the server or the proxy closing the connection. Investigate that.

Comment: How could proxy close connection ?. There is just one place where it is configurated and I pasted this code. And i dont know how server can close connection. If server wait for response from db less than 6:40 min then everything is ok and server returns data to client. After this time throws socket exception.